# Selected column not showing up in created SQL table, if removed get ERROR: Attempt to insert fewer columns than specified after the INSERT table name

Tags: sql, sas

I have inherited a legacy SAS program. There is one line in this program that I cannot figure out why it exists.  It is a column that is selected in my insert into table phrase, but the selected column is not present in the output table. If I add that column into the create table section, or remove it from the insert into table section, I get an error. I am really confused!

The line of code in question:

```
PUT(%sysfunc(catx(0,&CurrYR,&CurrQtr)),6.) AS fld
```

Full code:

```
data mydata;
input Industry $ Variable $ Value ReferencePeriod;
datalines;
Manufacturing Assets 100 20204
Retail Assets 200 20204
Finance  Assets 500 20204
Travel  Assets 300 20204
Biotech  Assets 100 20204
;
run;

%let StartYr=20201;
%let EndYR=20204;

PROC SQL;               
CREATE TABLE mytable            
(       ReferencePeriod     char(6) 
    ,   INDUSTRY    char(6)
    ,   Variable        num
    ,   Value       num
); 
%MACRO GETDATA(From,To);    
    %DO %WHILE(&From<=&To);             
        %LET CurrYR = %substr(&From,1,4);
        %LET CurrQtr = %substr(&From,5,1);

    PROC SQL;
            INSERT INTO mytable
            SELECT      DISTINCT
                        PUT(%sysfunc(catx(0,&CurrYR,&CurrQtr)),6.) AS fld ,
                    /*  ReferencePeriod, */
                        INDUSTRY
                    ,   Variable
                    ,   Value
            FROM        work.mydata
            GROUP BY    
                        PUT(%sysfunc(catx(0,&CurrYR,&CurrQtr)),6.)
                    ,   Industry
                    ,   Variable
            ;
        QUIT;
    %IF &CurrQtr = 4 
            %THEN %LET From = %eval(&CurrYR+1)1;
            %ELSE %LET From = &CurrYR%eval(&CurrQtr+1);
    %END;
%MEND;

%GETDATA(&StartYR,&EndYR);
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the code?  Why is it inserting the same records 4 times (with only a change to the first variable's value)?

Comment: Why is the variable named VARIABLE numeric in the target dataset and character in the source dataset?  Why is the variable ReferencePeriod character in the target dataset and numeric in the source dataset?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the query is generating a value to go into ReferencePeriod.

It might have been clearer if they had written it as

```
PUT(%sysfunc(catx(0,&CurrYR,&CurrQtr)),6.) AS ReferencePeriod
```

Answer (score 0):

The section you highlighted should work but is unnecessarily confusing.

I suspect that the real problem is you are grouping by only three of the four variables you are generating.  Why do you have the GROUP BY clause? Is that last "Value" variable really some type of aggregate function call?  Like SUM() or MIN() or MAX()?  If not the remove the GROUP BY clause.

And why are you including that first variable in the GROUP BY?  It is a constant so PROC SQL is just going issue a note saying that it will ignore it when finding the groups.

As to the confusing code:

In general there is no need to use CATX() or other functions to concatenate macro variable values.  Just expand the macro variable where you want its value to appear.

So

```
PUT(%sysfunc(catx(0,&CurrYR,&CurrQtr)),6.)
```

could be much more easily written (and more easily understood) as

```
"&CurrYR.0&CurrQtr"
```

Since CURRYR always has 4 characters and CURRQTR always has 1 character the result is a 6 character string with a zero inserted before the last character.

You don't need to give the constant you are generating from the macro variables a name (FLD in your uncommented code) but if you did want to use one then it is less confusing to use the same name as the variable you are inserting into.

```
"&CurrYR.0&CurrQtr" as ReferencePeriod
```